# how to solve the bool function that return one value in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following function:

```
public bool CheckConn()
    {
        try
        {
            if (JvarConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                JvarConn.Open();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
            MessageBox.Show("No Connection");
        }
        
    }
```

but there is a red line error under the function name and the error is:

> not all code paths return value

I tried to not putting a false value but the same error!. how can I solve that problem?

Comment: This is your opportunity to learn how to read/diagnose code. Go line through line and remember the branches as you go. There are 3 branches in your code, and there are only 2 `return` statements.

Comment: Seems that you're missing a return statement after the if brackets, as if the condition is not valid then there's no action or return statement that returns a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `return true;`, just before the method closing bracket `}`. It’s giving error because what if it doesn’t meet the `if`.

Im returning `true` based on your method name declaration and implementation inside.

Comment: Please stop answering these typo questions and **please** read [answer] once and for all. You have a lot of reputation already, you should know and understand that we don't need these questions **at all** on this site, and that you need to downvote, vote to close and move on rather than answer.
Finally, this **teaches nothing** to the person asking the question.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sorry for that, I’ll definitely take care next time.